# How to make marque text in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I read many info about marque text with UILabel, so it's easy to make. I have question about UITableViewCell. For example i have big text in title and i want to make scroll for my big text in cell.textLabel or detailTextLabel. So also i tried:

Make this with AutoScrollLabel class - nothing and have some problem in iOS 7.
I take CBAutoScrollLabel - but it's class only for UIlabel.

So i can not paste some example code, because i have only simple cell.textLabel for show text from JSON o other text. Please help with this problem or maybe paste direct link.

Comment: How about creating a custom cell with CBAutoScrollLabel?

Comment: Try to solve this problem by creating custom Uitableviewcell because you need to set the UIlabel to superclass of CBAutoScrollLabel .So, it will help you to solve this issue.

Comment: See down post, it's possible to make without superclass. Only addSubview and it will be work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the cell to a custom cell and give it an identifier like "cell"

Now you you can simply use the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     CBAutoScrollLabel *captionLabel = [[CBAutoScrollLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)]; //can use any value you want here. 

     captionLabel.tag = 1;

     // setup your label here

     [cell addSubview:captionLabel];

     return cell;

}
```

If you are having issues with reusability, you can do the follwoing:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     CBAutoScrollLabel *captionLabel = (CBAutoScrollLabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
     [captionLabel removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: It's work! Perfectly work! but when i scroll list my text paste and paste and paste on the one...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: See screen on my dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gmlshyhoghglan/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202014-03-09%20%C3%A0%2000.37.39.png

Comment: it was when i made scroll up or down in my tableView. Text superimposed on each other

Comment: It might might be because of the reusability of the cells. Try deleting the UILabel when the cell disappears.

Comment: How it's make? Because i can not find about this problem. Thanks Mikael